# Python 2.x sublist parameter equivalent in 3.x

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I'm working some NLP experiments in Python and wanted to implement this function in Python 3.x though the lambda expansion here is giving me a hard time and I'm not sure how it'd be implemented in 3.x; any suggestions?

```
    candidates = [' '.join(word for word, pos, chunk in group).lower()
              for key, group in itertools.groupby(all_chunks, lambda (word,pos,chunk): chunk != 'O') if key]
```

The error I get is on this piece since sublist parameters are not supported in 3.x

```
lambda (word,pos,chunk)
```

The original source is the extract_candidate_words function here: http://bdewilde.github.io/blog/2014/09/23/intro-to-automatic-keyphrase-extraction/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The syntax in Python3 would be:

```
lambda word__pos__chunk: word__pos__chunk[2] != 'O'
```

A `lambda` function with a three item tuple `(word, pos, chunk)` gets converted to `word__pos__chunk` with positional arguments,  `word__pos__chunk[2]` access the third item for example.

more information: [pep-3113](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/)

Comment: This seems to imply that the double underscores have special meaning, but in fact it doesn't; `word__pos__chunk` is just a regular tuple, and `word__pos__chunk[2]` accesses the third item in it.

Comment: I have not tried to confuse, I have updated the way to express it forgive my English.

Comment: Not sure why this got a downvote - perhaps I'm missing something. The syntax itself was exactly what I needed, thanks.